# Jmeter - The time taken by first iteration of http sampler is large

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I have written a http sampler which I am running for 5 iteration and this is the reading I have been getting

805
160
148
185
143

What I am noticing is the time taken for first iteration is large as compared to last four. I am observing the same everytime I am running the sampler. 
Just for info I have following things off in the http sampler
UseKeepAlive= off
https.use.cached.ssl.context=false in the jmeter file.

Question is why it may be happening.

Answer (score 3):

Hi there are many ways this can happen:

1. first time you run Jmeter (e.g from command line), it may take some time time to load libraries, custom jars etc. I found it is a good practice to introduce a warm up phase with a separate thread group.
2. the same may happen at server side. In these case however, you should see that only the very first sample is slower. The following samples should find the .jars an d.jsp already loaded/ compiled.
3. Check the HTTP cache settings: if you have large objects (images and/or movies and so on): the objects are downloaded once and then kept in the client cache.
4. there are many cache levels inside an application that you should investigate. E.g., if you read some data from a DB, and the data remains constant for each test, probably the data are read once and then kept in cache.